Объем БД в postgresql
Необходимо посчитать объем БД на конец года, для этого хотел узнать размер одной строки.
Сначала думал считать примитивно, взять объем (на скрине справа) и поделить на количество строк.

Но получилась очень большая цифра, около 9 000 байт. Понял, что там хранятся секции и индексы, но их объем не пишется.
Запросом pg_column_size выдает размер строки около 100 байт (суммировал все столбцы).
Разница огромная...
Как корректно можно посчитать и запланировать объем на конец года?
Использую DBeaver

Но ведь при увеличении количества строк объём индексов тоже увеличивается.

Некоторое время следить за  объемом, потом сделать прогноз.
    SELECT 
    d.datname AS database_name,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(d.datname)) AS database_size
    FROM 
    pg_database d

